# Vuejs input with v-model not updating when I sanitize the input on a watch handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm using Vue 2.6 and I am encountering a weird problem when I sanitize an input.

I have a custom component for the actual input that is basically the following (I add some styling etc that is not relevant here):

```
<template>
  <input :name="name" :value="value" @input="(e) => onInput(e.target.value)" />
</template>
```

where `onInput` simply emits the `input` event, and both `value` and `name` are props.

I can use this component on my page:

```
<Field v-model="field" name="field" />
```

It works greatly on most cases.

The problem started because I need to remove all lowercase and whitecase characters from the input. So I created a watch handler on `field`:

```
onFieldChange(field) {
  this.field = field.replace(/[\sa-z]/gi, '')
}
```

Now, if I start typing something invalid like      `test` and I inspect the Vue components, I can see that the `field` is correctly `''`, because all the invalid chars are stripped away, but I keep seeing      `test` inside the input.

If I also add a valid char, such as `T` =>      `testT` then it renders correctly to only be `T`.

It's clear to me what is the problem origin: my `Field` component does not see any difference in its props ('value' remains the same, an empty string) and so it does not re-render. But I don't understand how I could solve it, do you have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your field value in nextTick.

```
onFieldChange(field) {
  this.$nextTick(()=>{
    this.field = this.field.replace(/[\sa-z]/gi, '')
  })
  // this.field = field.replace(/[\sa-z]/gi, '')
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s52a9ctn/)